# Failed to install native resource: Linux-lib.jar

Tags: java, linux, opensuse

I have installed openSUSE 42.3 as a guest on host MAC OS. Whenever I am  installing SAPGUI for JAVA 7.40 rev 12, I get following error:

"Failed to install native resource: Linux-lib.jar"

There is a directory "JDK-10" inside the home directory. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this SAP community posting](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3375038), the problem occurs when you try to use the SAPGui installer for Mac OS on a Linux machine.

It won't work.  You need to use the SAPGui installer for Linux to install SAPGui in your openSUSE guest VM.

Comment: Ok thanks, but where can I get the SAPGui Installer For Linux?